# Sum of powers in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

I have trouble following the logic in [this proof](http://acuteproofaday.blogspot.com/2014/10/sum-of-powers-in-finite-fields.html). In particular, why is the following equality is true:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{x \in K^\times} x^u = \displaystyle\sum_{x \in K^\times} y^u x^u$$

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1268419/11619). +1 to y'all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $y \in K^{\times}$, the map $\varphi_y : K^{\times} \to K^{\times}$, $x \mapsto yx$ is a bijection (with inverse $\varphi_{y^{-1}}$). So the only difference between the two summations is the order of the summands, so they are equal.

For example, if $u = 1$, $K = \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, and $y = 2$, then we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{x\in K^{\times}}x &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4\\
\sum_{x\in K^{\times}}2x &= 2 + 4 + 1 + 3.
\end{align*}

Comment: So is there any explicit reason the blogger mentions we can let $y$ equal a generator?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why the author chooses $y$ such that $y^u \neq 1$?

Comment: The author says "We can let $y$ be a generator of $K^\times$". But as you say, $\varphi_y$ is a bijection as $y \in K^\times$.

Comment: Implying $y \in K^\times$ need not be a generator.

Comment: Choosing $y$ to be a generator guarantees that $y^u \neq 1$ as $u$ is not divisible by $q - 1$.

Comment: Both of the above sums are zero in $\mathbb{Z}/5$

Comment: @orangeskid: Of course. The proof that the OP refers to shows that they must be zero.