# Prove that $S_k(p)= \begin{cases} -1, & \text{if $(p-1)\mid k$ } \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ in $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, cyclic-groups

Consider $\Bbb Z_p= \Bbb Z/{p \Bbb Z}$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Now denote $S_k(p)= \sum _{j=0}^{p-1} j^k$ in $\Bbb Z_p$

> The problem is to prove that $S_k(p)= \begin{cases}
> -1,  & \text{if $(p-1)\mid k$ } \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$ in $\Bbb Z_p$

Now we know $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$, so in the first case if we have $k=a(p-1)$, then $\forall j \in \Bbb Z_p^*$ we have $j^k=j^{(p-1)a}=1$. Hence $S_k(p)=p-1=-1$ in $\Bbb Z_p$

if $(p-1)$ does not divide $k$ then I am having problem.
If $\gcd(p-1,k)=1$ then $S_k(p)= \sum _{j=0}^{p-1} j=p(p-1)/2=0$ in $\Bbb Z_p$

But for the other cases?? Please help and explain in details.

Comment: You know that the group is cyclic. Let $g$ be a generator. Can you express $\sum j^k$ in terms of $g$?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization.

Comment: If $(p-1)\nmid k$ then there exists $a\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ such that $a^k\neq1$. But then
$$S_k(p)=\sum_jj^k=\sum_j(aj)^k=a^k\sum_jj^k=a^kS_k(p).$$
This implies $S_k(p)=0.$

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate. [This is a close match](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707013/11619). I answered that one, so I probably shouldn't vote to close this a dupe. Also, I think there's a more direct dupe.

Comment: [This is a closer match](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268419/sum-of-elements-of-a-finite-field), though also not an exact duplicate.

Comment: [Another related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2365442/11619) with the same trick. May be the one that I think of as the oldest didn't have powers, and therefore I can't find it now :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma(I)**: 
Let $p$ to be an odd prime, 
then $\big(  \mathbb{Z}_p^* , .  \big)$ is a **cyclic** group.

---

**Lemma(II)**: 
For every $i \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$; 
we have: $i \mathbb{Z}_p^* = \mathbb{Z}_p^*$.

---

**Lemma(III)**: 
Let $p$ to be an odd prime, 
and let $k$ to be any arbitrary integer.

- If $p-1 \mid k$; 
  then for every $j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$; 
  we have: 
  $j^k \overset{p}{\equiv} 1$.
- If $p-1 \nmid k$; 
  then there exists $l \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$; 
  such that: 
  $l^k \overset{p}{\ncong} 1$.

---

**Proof**:

- The first statement is the trivial result of fermat's little theorem.
- Second statement: 
  Let $\varepsilon$ to be a generator of 
  $\big(  \mathbb{Z}_p^* , .  \big)$;
  and let $d:=\gcd(k,p-1)$.
  Also let $t:=\dfrac{p-1}{d}$;
  then it is easy to check that 
  for every $r$, with $\gcd(r,t)=1$;
  we have: 
  $(\varepsilon^r)^k \overset{p}{\ncong} 1$.

---

**Lemma(IV)**: 
Let $G$ be any group 
and $a \in G$ any element of finite order. Then we have: 
$$\text{ord}(a^t)=\dfrac{\text{ord}(a)}{\gcd(\text{ord}(a),t)}.$$

---

---

---

---

- If $p-1 \mid k$; 
  then for every $j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$; 
  we have: 
  $j^k \overset{p}{\equiv} 1$. 
  So the sum 
  $ 
  {\sum}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}j^k= 
  {\sum}_{j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}  1= 
  p-1=-1.$
- If $p-1 \nmid k$; 
  then there exists $l \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$; 
  such that: 
  $l^k \overset{p}{\ncong} 1$. 
  Notice that: 
  $$ 
  \color{Blue}{ 
       {\sum}_{ j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*} j^k     }= 
       {\sum}_{lj \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*} (lj)^k  = 
       {\sum}_{ j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*} l^kj^k  = 
  \color{Red}{l^k}  
  \color{Blue}{ 
       {\sum}_{ j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}    j^k  } 
  \\ 
  \Longrightarrow 
  (1-\color{Red}{l^k}  )
  \color{Blue}{ 
       {\sum}_{ j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}    j^k  } = 
  0 ; 
  $$ 
  but notice that 
  $(1-\color{Red}{l^k}  )$ is not zero;
  which implies that: 
  $\color{Blue}{ 
       {\sum}_{ j \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*}    j^k  }=0$.

Comment: Could you please tell me that what intuition did you get to find that $r$ so that you can view Firstly that $\epsilon ^r$ will be your $l$?

Comment: @ user152715  
**Lemma(IV)**: 
Let $G$ be any group 
and $a \in G$ any element of finite order. Then we have: 
$$\text{ord}(a^t)=\dfrac{\text{ord}(a)}{\gcd(\text{ord}(a),t)}.$$