# Number of solutions of $x^n = 1 \pmod{p}$ for every integer $n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory, group-homomorphism

> In the integers modulo $p$, $p$ a prime, there are at most $n$ solutions of $x^n = 1 \pmod{p}$ for every integer $n$.

I was wondering if there is any proof which only uses group theory and no field theory. This is a question asked in supplementary exercise of Herstein's group theory.

Comment: Maybe you can argue about the order of x?

Comment: Without a bound on $x$ this is trivially false, e. g. $x = 1$, $x = 3$ for $n = 1$, $p = 2$.

Comment: Maybe you find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399615/roots-of-an-equation-over-the-finite-field-operatornamegfpq) useful.

Comment: Looking at Herstein, we see that the next exercise is: "Prove that the nonzero integers mod $p$ under multiplication form a cyclic group". So, this result cannot be used to answer the question.