# A congruence involving Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, primality-test

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample to the following claim :

> Let $n$ be a natural number greater than one and let $ F_{n}(x)$ be [Fibonacci polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials) , then $n$ is prime if and only if : $ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F_{n}(k) \equiv -1 \pmod n$  .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jEsOwjAMRPdIXKIrmxgpgaXxEbgEkIqo-VhpqlZC3J10w2o0b0Yvy9Xx8TCGByTaUD5qxbI6cRzlwus7RA_xJolUtpM6o321om7_KEdjkKtvS82g-O2mMALcywvmJcEklvLZ0W7PNCFSRpFOkLSG3GDokfzwr8-StMyhdYT8A9puLpQ=&lang=gp) .

Comment: For 1729 it gives prime albeit 1729 being composite.

Comment: @Richard Did you run pari/gp code provided  by me ?

Comment: I did, now I tested it again and it gave "composite" and the third time a syntax error.

Comment: I wonder what $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F_{n}(k)  \bmod n$ is in general.

Comment: Maybe the fact that $F_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1-i}{i}x^{n-2i-1}$ could be used, somehow... (some exchange of summation order and stuff perhaps)

Comment: This probably helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2731471/589, at least for one direction.

Answer (score 2):

One direction, proving $\sum_{k} F_p(k)\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ when $p$ is prime, is easy.

Let $\sigma_i=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k^i$, and let  $f_{i}$ be the coefficient of $x^i$ in $F_p(x)$. Then $\sum_{k} F_p(k)\equiv \sum_i f_{i}\sigma_i$. [You can show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268419/sum-of-elements-of-a-finite-field) $\sigma_i\equiv0$ for all $i=0,1,\dots,p-2$, while $\sigma_{p-1}\equiv-1$. Since the $x^{p-1}$ coefficient of $F_{p}(x)$ is $1$, the result follows.