# Factoring Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

A numerical evidence given by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+Fibonacci%5B37,x%5D+mod+37) strongly suggests that, when $p$ is an odd prime, the [Fibonacci polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials) $F_{p}(x)$ factors mod $p$ explicitly as follows:
$$
F_{p}(x) = (x^2+4)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}
$$

I've love to see a proof. You may want to start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2731208/589).

The factorization above can be refined as follows:

- If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then $x^2+4=(x-a)(x+a)$, where $a^2 \equiv -4 \bmod p$.
- If $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, then  $x^2+4$ is irreducible mod $p$.

but this is well known.

Comment: Motivated by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731172/values-of-fibonacci-polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the "Identities" section of the Wikipedia article you linked to, one has for all $n$
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + 4}F_n(x) = (\alpha(x) - \beta(x))F_n(x) = \alpha(x)^n - \beta(x)^n
$$
where
$$
\alpha(x) = \frac{x + \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \beta(x) = \frac{x - \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2}.
$$
Thus when $p$ is an odd prime number we have in $\mathbb{Z}_p(x)[\sqrt{x^2 + 4}]$
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + 4}F_p(x) = \alpha(x)^p - \beta(x)^p = (\alpha(x) - \beta(x))^p = \sqrt{x^2 + 4}^p.
$$

The used explicit formula for $F_n(x)$ can be derived by diagonalizing the matrix of the recurrence relation as N. S. did. Alternatively, it can be proved by induction. A proof by induction is shorter, but does not provide the insight that the matrix approach does (i.e. it does not show how one would every come up with such a formula).

Comment: I don't know how I missed that in Wikipedia!

Answer (score 3):

**Attempted solution, I think that this works:**

The case $p=2$ is easy, so let us set $p \neq 2$.

Consider the recurrence
$$F_{n+1}(X)=XF_{n}(X)+F_{n-1}(X)$$
in the field $\mathbb Z_p(X)$.

Then, by a standard argument 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
F_{n+1}(X) \\
F_n(X) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} X & 1 \\1 &0 \end{bmatrix} ^n \begin{bmatrix}
F_{1}(X) \\
F_0(X) \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic equation of $\begin{bmatrix} X & 1 \\1 &0 \end{bmatrix} $ is 
$$Y^2-XY-1=0$$
with solutions 
$$Y=\frac{X \pm \sqrt{X^2+4}}{2}$$
either in $\mathbb Z_p(X)$ or in an algebraic extension $\mathbb Z_p(X) \subseteq K$ of degree 2.

Since the eigenvalues are distinct, by Diagonalizing the matrix we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
F_{p+1}(X) \\
F_p(X) \end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix} \left(\frac{X + \sqrt{X^2+4}}{2}\right)^p & 0 \\0 &\left(\frac{X - \sqrt{X^2+4}}{2}\right)^p\end{bmatrix} P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
F_{1}(X) \\
F_0(X) \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, using the Frobenius homomorphism we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
F_{p+1}(X) \\
F_p(X) \end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}\frac{X^p + (X^2+4)^\frac{p}{2}}{2^p} & 0 \\0 &\frac{X^p - (X^2+4)^\frac{p}{2}}{2^p}\end{bmatrix} P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
F_{1}(X) \\
F_0(X) \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, **if everything works nicely**, when we calculate $P,P^{-1}$ explicitly (this can likely be done with software) you get the desired result.

Comment: I think that the above computation gives the desired result, but I am too lazy to calculate $P, P^{-1}$.

Comment: Of course, the matrix approach!

Comment: @Ilf I find the matrix approach natural for this type of problems: Just write $$F_{n+1}(X)=XF_{n}(X)+F_{n-1}(X)\\F_n(X)=F_n(X)$$ and the matrix recurrence relation becomes natural. This also emphasizes that a recurrence like this is just a first order matrix recurrence, people forget often that the matrix recurrence is much easier to study.